# Неправильный алгоритм склонения сопряженных с числительными слов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Наблюдается ошибка в алгоритме склонения сопряженных с числительными слов:

После числительных, оканчивающихся на  2, 3, 4 нужно ставить слова в единственном числе родительном падеже (*132 показ-**а***) - как и сделано (но не везде), однако для числительных, заканчивающихся на 1х, (х = 0..9) нужно ставить слова во множественном числе родительном падеже ( 113 *показ-**ов***) - не сделано

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: Где именно? Сделайте, плиз, скриншот. При переводе такие штуки должны были учитываться, так что это баг.

Comment: @VladD, добавил

Comment: Спасибо. Ждём, что скажет администрация.

Comment: Поправили. Скорее всего, строки обновятся завтра. Спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Багфикс покрывает и это тоже? Или нужен отдельный вопрос? http://i.imgur.com/BkUODQT.jpg

Comment: @VladD Это тоже поправили.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Ура! Спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: А когда выкатят обновление на сайт?

Comment: Не раньше завтрашнего дня.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky так и не поправили же!